# objective-c coredata to-many fetch performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

(using core-data w/ underlying sqlite; wondering the run-time of calls im making with to-many getters)

if i have a following relationship in core-data

Book <--->> Chapter

then,

NSSet *chapters = book.chapters;

how fast is this getter access (which would fire fault)?

would it be going through the entire chapter-table to find the chapters that belong to this book? such that, longer the chapter-table is, worse the performance? 
(e.g. if i had 1,000 books each with 10 chapters, then would this traverse the entire 10,000 records in chapter-table?)

i keep going between whether to have chapters as a separate table or simply have

transformable(NSArray) chapters attributes on a book.

that way, obviously i don't have to worry about all the other chapters in other books...

i made chapters as its own table originally because i wanted to avoid having transformable nsarrays if i'm also going to be saving chapters to coredata anyway... but now i'm worried about performance implications of this once # of books get large (which in turn would increase # of chapters total in chapter-table)

Comment: Stop thinking in tables. Core data is about objects and it's relationships. ONE way CoreData is able to save the data is as SQLite tables. So I really would NOT store the Chapters in an transformable Array. In the dimension you described above, the access should be rapidly fast.

Comment: The assignment performance is the same for 1 or for a million chapters. It is just assigning a pointer!

Comment: @Merlevede this is about core-data; it's not just about assigning pointers; before that assignment happens, [book chapters] this message itself fires fault, and causes the underlying sqlite table to be fetched with specific SELECT query; and i'm concerned about whether the performance of that query is proportional to the #of records in chapters-table

Comment: @SaschaHameister code-design wise, yes; but when i'm thinking about performance, i can't ignore the run-time of the calls i'm making. i'm basically wondering what the run-time of this getter-call is. is this basically O(n) where n= # of records in chapters-table (including chapters of other books) as opposed to O(1) if this was a transformable attribute

Comment: It's definitely not O(n), because you did not accessed an object in the Set. The set contains just faults, until you acess them firstly.

Comment: even to fetch those faults, how do you know which chapters would need to be returned as faults unless you went through the entire chapter-table first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not do a full table scan because there will be a foreign key relationship in the underlying table when you use SQLite.  You can improve performance up to a certain point but eventually you **must** fault the data into memory to work with it.  The "when" of that faulting is your control over performance.

In a one to many relationship the size of the many table is not going to impact you either at creation or fetch time because of the relationships.  The only performance penalty you are going to feel on a large table is if you do a query against said table.  As long as you never query that table directly you will not have performance issues.

On the other size, putting your chapters in an `NSArray` *will* **destroy** performance.  That is putting binary data (a blob) into a table.  You will not be able to search it and any attempts to fetch against that table are going to repeatedly blow out the cache in the `NSFetchedResultsController` causing nearly constant disk access.

Please don't do that.